# How to navigate to another html file using apache tomcat servlets and send jinja variables?

Tags: java, html, tomcat, servlets

Using flask python in order to render another template and send over jinja variables on get request you can simply do the following:

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Ensure username was submitted
        username = request.form.get("username"):
        password = request.form.get("password"):
        # Redirect user to home page
        return render_template("home.html", username=username)

    # User reached route via GET
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
```

what is its equivalent on Java using tomcat Servlets?

Comment: In your python code, you're not actually redirecting. You're just rendering the content that would be on the "home" page, but your user is still on your login route.

Answer (score 0):

Using Servlets you need two parts: the configuration file (web.xml) and the Servlet code.

1. Set the configuration into the web.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Servlet Example</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <!-- you will want to take a look at jsp as well --> 
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login Servlet</servlet-name>
    <!-- dont forget to put the canonical name, including the package name -->
    <servlet-class>com.example.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
</web-app>
```

1. Then you code the servlet:

   ```
   package com.example;
   public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

   // GET
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws ServletException, IOException {
       response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
   }

   // POST
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws ServletException, IOException {
       String username = request.getParameter("username");
       String password = request.getParameter("password");

       // method credentialsOk validate the user/password
       if(credentialsOk(username, password)){
           response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
       }else{
           response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
       }
    }
   ```

   }

Take a look here for a Servlet introduction: https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-servlets

Comment: This looks great but I still don't get how to send jinja variables to the html file

Comment: @AmmarMohamed the render_template function get the parameters and pass to template engine. In your example, when using POST you pass the 'username=username', it should have a {{ username }} inside your jinja template code so the render_template username variable will be used by the jinja engine template.

Comment: In Java is similar but instead of using jinja templates you use Jsp pages. Take a look here to see how it works: https://www.baeldung.com/jsp